# "цикличный" поиск в регулярных выражениях

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо проверить номера телефонов, которые написаны в виде обычной последовательности 10 цифр без разделителей. Проблема в том, что номеров телефонов может быть несколько (перечисленных через запятую), поэтому они вводятся в input text, а значит, пользователь может ввести туда букву.

Простая регулярка `[\d]{10}|[,]` находит последовательность 10 цифр, либо запятую, но меня не устроит что в строке "9543243443, 9512345567б" она не выдаст ошибку, так как указанные сочетания найдены (не смотря на букву б в конце второго телефона). Написать регулярку на поиск любых символов *кроме* цифр и запятой, я не могу, так как в методе, написанном не мною, регулярка прогоняется через `! preg_match()` и только при возвращении `true` сгенерится ошибка. Другими словами, я должен написать регулярку, которая проверит что *всё* выражение есть последовательность 10-ти цифр, разделенных запятой (а может и нет, если телефон один) и если это не так - ошибка.

Я не работал ранее с регулярками, поэтому у меня вопрос: можно ли заставить регулярку проверять строку сегментировано, по кусочкам. Проверил первый сегмент(10 цифр) - ок, проверил второй сегмент(10 цифр) - ок, на третьем сегменте не 10 цифр - стоп, ошибка.

Comment: разделите через explode, и проверьте дальше отдельно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение вашего вопроса

```
/^(\d{10})$|^(\d{10},)+(\d{10})$/
```

если вам нужен будет пробел, то нужно будет доработать выражение

Comment: что-то если во второй части вместо плюса сделать звездочку. то первая и не понадобится

Comment: @teran, спасибо, полезное дополнение.

Answer (score 2):

Через запятую без пробелов:

```
^(\d{10}($|,))+$
```

Через запятую с разрешёнными после неё пробелами:

```
^(\d{10}($|,\s*))+$
```

Через запятую с пробелами вне номеров телефонов:

```
^\s*(\d{10}\s*($|,)\s*)+$
```

Comment: Вместо `\s` я бы рекомендовал использовать `\h` - горизонтальные пробельные символы

Comment: @ipatev_nn, ну если движок позволяет, то ok. На js такого нет.